# Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activerecord, migration

I just finished my first Ruby on Rails app, and I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku. I am now at the final step, but when I run the following command (heroku run rake db:migrate), I am getting this error :

```
StandardError : Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. 
Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for.
```

Everyone on the web is saying that you just have to change

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

to

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```

The problem is that this solution doesn't work for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What rails version are you using (i assume 4.2.x) ? Did you updated all your migrations?

Comment: Yeah, I use Rails 4.2 and I updated all my migrations...

Comment: That's a rails 5 error, so heroku thinks you've rails 5, I guess this doesn't happen locally. What exactly version do you have in the gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Add [5.1] if your ruby rails version is [5.1.5] even...just 5.1
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

like in this thread. Check in gemfile at the very top to see what version of rails you have.

I ran bundle install straight afters and
and I ran the command that originally showed this error and it worked then worked. Not sure you need to run bundle install though..

Hope this helps
Sput